# Angular taking control of the Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have this form snippet:

```
<form name="registerForm" novalidate role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns"><label for="pwd" class="right inline">Password:</label></div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <label class="" ng-class="{'error': registerForm.pwd.$error.required && registerForm.pwd.$dirty}"><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" ng-model="registerDetails.password" ng-required="true" /></label>
            <small class="error" ng-show="registerForm.pwd.$error.required && registerForm.pwd.$dirty">Password Required</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And as you can see there is this `registerForm.pwd` which is the form name plus the input name. Angular has added things like `$error` and `$dirty` to this  variable.

Is there any way I can add my own to it? so like `registerForm.pwd.$notEqual` via a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes please see workink demo below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('validPasswordC', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {

      reference: '=validPasswordC'

    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue, $scope) {
        if (viewValue === "") {
          ctrl.$setValidity('_required', false)
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('_required', true)
        }

        var noMatch = viewValue != scope.reference
        ctrl.$setValidity('notEqual', !noMatch)
      });

      scope.$watch("reference", function(value) {;
        ctrl.$setValidity('notEqual', value === ctrl.$viewValue);

      });
    }
  }
});
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {




});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
  <form name="registerForm" novalidate role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <label for="pwd" class="right inline">Password:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-9 columns">
        <label class="" ng-class="{'error': registerForm.pwd.$error.required && registerForm.pwd.$dirty}">
          <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" ng-model="registerDetails.password" placeholder=" password" ng-required="true" />



        </label>
        <label for="pwd" class="right inline">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_c" name="pwdConfirm" ng-model="registerDetails.passwordConfirm" placeholder="confirm password" valid-password-c="registerDetails.password" ng-required="true" />

        <p class="error" ng-show="registerForm.pwd.$error.required && registerForm.pwd.$dirty">
          Password Required
        </p>
        <p ng-show="registerForm.pwdConfirm.$error.notEqual" class="error">
          Passwords do not match.
        </p>

        <p class="error" ng-show="registerForm.pwdConfirm.$error.required && registerForm.pwdConfirm.$dirty || registerForm.pwdConfirm.$error._required ">
          Confirmation Required
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I just want to make sure one thing is clear to viewers, `required: 'ngModel'` is required to be able to access `ctrl.$parsers.unshift`. I had `required: '^form'` and had issues

Comment: I don't believe it is actually, your demo is using the `pwd` required. Not the `pwdConfirm` one!

Comment: @No1_Melman I've thought that you mention required error for password not for confirmation, please see update demo

Comment: mine just isn't working, I'm not sure why I'll have to keep trying things

Comment: I'm using angular v1.3.2 and this version is v1.2.22 so I don't know if this makes a difference?

Comment: @No1_Melman I've added angular 1.3.2 to answer and you are right is not working. I've added extra validator '_required' and is working again please see demo

Comment: You legend, let me take a look!

Comment: It still gets an `ng-invalid-parse` and a `ng-invalid` class added, so it fails validation!